# Mail all values of $_POST array

Tags: php, html

I want to mail all the values that are send through form in a $_POST array.

I looped through the array for each element and stored it in another variable say $results concatinating the results.

But when I mail them, they are combined together

I used

`foreach($_POST as $key=> $value){
    $results .= $key .":".$value."\n";
}`

I even used `<br/>` in place of \n but same result, al values in the same line. What should i use?

Comment: where do you want to see them in separate line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard mail format uses `\r\n` not `\n`. Try using that style of new line.

Comment: I tried it, But i dont know why It  didnt worked. May be I did it incorrectly. I used table structure instead for it.

Comment: Perhaps you are having trouble with content-type. Are you delivering html or text email? Sounds like html. Have you looked at your text-only version?